# IAP Google Play and iTunes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to setup IAP Subscription with Google Play and iTunes.

I have copied the script from the Unity official site but the bit confused in subscription products.

In the following code,

```
builder.AddProduct(kProductIDSubscription, ProductType.Subscription, new IDs(){
                { kProductNameAppleSubscription, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { kProductNameGooglePlaySubscription, GooglePlay.Name },
            });
```

What is kProductIDSubscription and kProductNameAppleSubscription? What is ProductID in BuyProductID function?

Here is code: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

Answer (score 1):

`kProductIDSubscription` is just a generic ID (string defined in the code at line #28) that encapsulates apple and google stores so you don't have to refer to platform specific IDs.

This helps you do something like `BuyProductID(kProductIDSubscription);` instead of calling apple or google specific IDs.

Just make sure to use the string of `kProductNameAppleSubscription` when you are setting up the item on Apple app store

```
builder.AddProduct("my-generic-id", ProductType.Subscription, new IDs(){
            { "the-id-i-put-on-app-store", AppleAppStore.Name },
            { "the-id-i-put-on-google-store", GooglePlay.Name },
        });


//Somewhere where player is buying
BuyProductID("my-generic-id")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I have created a subscription on Google Play with product ID let say "XYZ". Then what would be the code to AddProduct subscription?

builder.AddProduct("subscription", ProductType.Subscription, new IDs(){
            { "XYZ", GooglePlay.Name }
            });

Is it correct?

Comment: and also we need to pass Product ID "XYZ" to the BuyProductID routine to subscribe this product?

Comment: No, in the BuyProductID you will pass the Unity specific ID. Although it can be same as your Google ID.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. What is my-generic-id? Is it Unique product ID that created in stores? or something else? 

Any possibility of sample code where I can refer?

Comment: It could anything you want, Doesn't have to be "my-generic-id". This id is what you will use inside Unity to buy stuff. The store specific IDs are the ones inside block like "the-id-i-put-on-app-store" which you will set up on the App store.